# Where should check for old browser be done(client or server)?

Tags: javascript, nginx, browser

We have an old browser check on client side right now and thinking about moving it to server side(nginx): to show old browser page immediately without loading the application.
Is it good idea? or it's better to keep this check in JS?

Comment: Neither. Feature detection and progressive enhancement is preferable. (But this is somewhat a matter of opinion, more so when the question is as general as this one).

Comment: good point. unfortunately we don't have resources for it